# Creating an Array of a class with an attribute integer(), all instances in the array, are overwritten with data of last instance added

Tags: arrays, replace

I am returning an array of the instance Trendclass, which includes three attributes. The datapoints_array is supposed to contain values. Unfortunately the datapoints of all instances are replaced as soon as a new one is added to the array, while timestamp and column_name remain as they are (as presented in Console). Is there a logical mistake? Am desperately trying to find a solution.

The Code is the following:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        testTrendclass()
    End Sub



    Public Function testTrendclass() As TrendClass()

        Dim array_length As Integer = 5
        Dim Trend_array(array_length) As TrendClass
        Dim duration As Integer = 10
        Dim datapoints_array(duration) As Integer


        For i = 0 To array_length
            For i2 = 0 To 5
                datapoints_array(i2) = i * i2
            Next

            Trend_array(i) = New TrendClass With {
                .column_name = "ISO1_MICRA1810_" & i,
                .datapoints = datapoints_array,
                .timestamp = System.DateTime.Now().AddDays(i)
            }
            Console.WriteLine("current_data_array")

            For i2 As Integer = 0 To 4
                Console.WriteLine("data_array: " & Trend_array(i).datapoints(i2))
            Next
            Console.WriteLine(vbLf & vbLf)
        Next



        For i = 0 To Trend_array.Count() - 1
            Console.WriteLine("column_name: " & Trend_array(i).column_name)
            For i2 As Integer = 0 To 4
                Console.WriteLine("data_array: " & Trend_array(i).datapoints(i2))
            Next
            Console.WriteLine("timestamp: " & Trend_array(i).timestamp & vbLf)
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()
        Return Trend_array
    End Function

    Public Class TrendClass

        Public Property timestamp As DateTime
        Public Property datapoints As Integer()
        Public Property column_name As String

    End Class

End Module
```

Comment: It's not that previous instances "are being replaced", but rather that you only ever have a single datapoints_array, so all your instances are pointing to the same object.  Try moving the declaration of datapoints_array to inside the "for i" loop.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution... Data is inserted ByReference, and therefore is overwriting its own values. Declaring the datapoints_array inside the for loop solved the problem:

Public Function testTrendclass() As TrendClass()

```
    Dim array_length As Integer = 5
    Dim Trend_array(array_length) As TrendClass
    Dim duration As Integer = 10


    For i = 0 To array_length

        Dim datapoints_array(duration) As Integer
        For i2 = 0 To 5
            datapoints_array(i2) = i * i2
        Next
```